# How to show entries from the current month?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For the sake of explanation, I'm writing an app where a User can log their expenses.

In the User's show view, I want to only show the User's expenses from the current month.

My expenses table looks like this:

```
create_table "expenses", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.date     "date"
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "cost"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer  "user_id"
end
```

The date field is in the date format, so looks like: `Thu, 14 Apr 2016`

In my controller, I've got something like:

```
def show
  month = Date.today.strftime("%m")
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @expenses = Expense.where(:user_id => @user.id, :date => month)
end
```

Obviously, this isn't going to work, but it will be something along these lines, I'm guessing?

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Which DB you are using?

Comment: Postgres - Sorry, forgot to mention!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually you can tackle it this way:

```
Expense.where(date: (Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month))
```

Where that defines a range that can be used as a `BETWEEN x AND y` clause.

If this is a common operation you might want to express the date as a separate column in `YYYYMM` format so that these are easily retrieved.

Comment: There's also `Date.today.all_month`

Comment: @Stefan That's even better!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MySQL, you can use the extract function, to create a .where like:

```
def show
  month = Date.today.strftime("%m")
  year  = Date.today.strftime("%y")
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @expenses = Expence.where('extract(month from `date`) = ? AND extract(year from `date`) = ? AND `user_id` = ?', month, year, @user.id)
end
```

Havent tested, although it should work.

**Sources:**
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: This doesn't take the current year into account.

Comment: Updated to use year too.

Comment: That's an extremely messy thing to do, and while it will work, it will be murder on performance. Also, whenever possible try and link to the latest version of the documentation, like 5.7.

Comment: That is true. The fastest way would be index on date and using a between (afaik). I just thought to mention this as an option too.